# Psuedo-inverse of block low-rank, symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I have a matrix that looks like

$$
D = \left[
    \begin{matrix} 
    c_1aa^T & c_2ab^T \\
    c_2ba^T & c_3bb^T
    \end{matrix}
    \right]
$$

where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are scalars and $a, b$ are $n \times 1$ vectors. Is it possible to efficiently calculate the pseudo-inverse of $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q_a$ and $Q_b$ be orthogonal matrices such that $Q_aa=\alpha e_1$ and $Q_bb=\beta e_1$, where $\alpha=\|a\|_2$, $\beta=\|b\|_2$, and $e_1=[1,0,\ldots,0]^T$. Such matrices can be constructed, e.g., by using the Householder reflections. Then with $Q:=Q_a\oplus Q_b$, 
$$
QDQ^T=\begin{bmatrix}c_1\alpha^2 e_1e_1^T & c_2\alpha\beta e_1e_1^T\\ c_2\alpha\beta e_1e_1^T & c_3\beta^2 e_1e_1^T\end{bmatrix}.
$$
You can see that what remains is a matrix with just $4$ entries placed in the north-west corners of each of the blocks. With a suitable permutation $P$ you can make $PQDQ^TP^T=:\tilde{D}$ to have zeros everywhere except the leading principal $2\times 2$ submatrix, that is, $\tilde{D}=\tilde{D}_2\oplus 0_{n-2}$, where
$$
\tilde{D}_2:=\begin{bmatrix}c_1\alpha^2 & c_2\alpha\beta \\ c_2\alpha\beta & c_3\beta^2\end{bmatrix}.
$$ 
It is easy to compute the pseudoinverse of $\tilde{D}$:
$$
\tilde{D}^+=\tilde{D}_2^{+}\oplus 0_{n-2},
$$
where $\tilde{D}_2^{+}$ can be computed by inverting $\tilde{D}_2$ if it is nonsingular (if it is singular, then computing its pseudoinverse is also very cheap). The pseudoinverse of $D=Q^TP^T\tilde{D}PQ$ is then
$$
D^+=Q^TP^T\tilde{D}^+PQ.
$$

Comment: Is it possible to compute the Householder reflections in linear time or are they more expensive? It seems like that's the only potentially-costly part of this approach and I'm not finding any references for the complexity of computing them.

Comment: @WesleyTansey The Householder transformation has the form $Q=I-2vv^T$ for some unit $v$. Computing $v$ is linear. It is not a good idea to form $Q$ explicitly but rather consider its action on a vector $Qx=x-2(v^Tx)v$, which is linear. Consequently, applying $D^+$ (in the factored form as shown in the last row of the answer) is linear.

Comment: Great! And would this approach still hold if the diagonal blocks were rank-1 plus a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @WesleyTansey Well, rank-1 + diagonal is something else. You could probably scale symmetrically the matrix to make the diagonal matrices equal to the identity (if the diagonal elements are positive) and then do the similar thing again (identity will remain the identity when multiplied by the same $Q$ symmetrically from both sides). Or use the Sherman-Morisson formula in some form.